# How to send props value to styled component in emotion react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I am new to MUI and react, I am trying make input textbox component to reuse them, instead of creating every time.

I am trying to set `width` value by passing as a props. how can I achieve it.

**InputText - functional comp**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { Box } from '@mui/system'

type propsInputText ={
  width:string;
}

const TextBox = styled.input`
    width:${props => props.width? props.width : '30px;'}  
`

function InputText(props: propsInputText) {
  return (
    <TextBox />
  )
}

export default InputText
```

**MainPage - components**

```
import InputText from '../Tools/TextBox/InputText';

<InputText width='200px' />
```

**Note**

It is not just to set width only, I am trying pass anything to styled components ex: color,font-size,height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I just forget to pass the parameter on the functional component,

```
type propsInputText ={
  width:string;
}

const TextBox = styled.input`
    width:${props => props.width? props.width : '30px;'}  
`

function InputText(props: propsInputText) {
    console.log("InputText Props = "+props.width);
    return (
          <TextBox width={props.width} />    //here I need to add the props
    )
}

export default InputText
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
const InputBox = (props) => {
  const TextBox = styled.input(({ theme }) => ({
    width: props.width ? props.width : 200,
    color: props.color ? props.color : "blue",
    background: props.background? props.background : "yellow",
    height: props.height? props.height : 40
  }));
  return <TextBox />;
};
```

And then you could implement it like this:

```
<>
    <InputBox width={100} color={"white"} background={"black"} height={"10"} />
    <InputBox />
</>
```